# Publicly Accessible Objects in PHP Class

Tags: java, php

I'm looking to re-write a Java application I've built into PHP.

The Java wrapper class I'm to looking to re-write is (dumbed-down) in the following format:

```
package myPackage;
import webServiceStub.WebServiceEndpoint;
import webServiceStub.WebServiceSearch;

public class myClass {

    public static WebServiceEndpoint ep = new WebServiceEndpoint();
    public static WebServiceSearch search = new WebServiceSearch();

    public static List doSearch(String searchTerm){        
        search.setSearch(searchTerm);
        List result = ep.doSearch(search).getList();
        return result;
    }

}
```

So, this doSearch() function is being called asynchronously on each keystroke, with the WebServiceSearch object (search) being updated and sent off to the web service to return a result.

If I was searching for an address, the object is being added to, like so:

```
search = "1"
search = "1 m"
search = "1 ma"
search = "1 mai"
search = "1 main"
search = "1 main s"
search = "1 main st"
```

..and so on.

This is nice, as the object doesn't have to get instantiated (thus being cleared) each time the doSearch() function is called, making it nice and quick.

How can I replicate this in PHP?

E.g. **What I Want**:

```
<?php

require_once('webServiceStub.php');

// Looking for the PHP equivalent of the following type of global object 
// instantiation:

WebServiceEndpoint $ep = new WebServiceEndpoint();
WebServiceSearch $search = new WebServiceSearch();

class myClass {

    function doSearch($searchTerm) {
        $search->Search = $searchTerm;

        $resultList = $ep->DoSearch($search);

        return $resultList;
    }
}
?>
```

The only way I can get this PHP version working at the minute, is by creating a new instance of both the WebServiceEndpoint and WebServiceSearch objects every time the doSearch() function is called on each keystroke, which is ridiculously slow.

i.e. **What I Have**:

```
<?php

require_once('webServiceStub.php');

class myClass {

    function doSearch($searchTerm) {

        WebServiceEndpoint $ep = new WebServiceEndpoint();
        WebServiceSearch $search = new WebServiceSearch();

        $search->Search = $searchTerm;

        $resultList = $ep->DoSearch($search);

        return $resultList;
    }
}
?>
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and it's just hanging around like a dodgy smell. Can anyone shed any light on it?

(I'm clearly not much of a developer, I can just wing it)

Cheers in advance

Comment: Are you trying to mix up java and php together.?

Comment: No, just re-writing the Java example (provided at the top) in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To consume your class, at the bottom of your file, you can:

```
$mc = new myClass();
$result = $mc->doSearch("foo");
//echo $result;
//echo json_encode($result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how to consume the class, what I'm looking for is:

Class{
    global Variables here

    function here that can access the above global variables
}